# Setting Apache VirtualHost up for proper SNI handshake

Tags: apache, ssl, sni

I have a problem with an Apache machine that won't match the server name expected from the client, resulting in a warning:

TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Warning, Description: Unrecognized Name)

I am pretty sure this has to do with my VirtualHost configuration. Though I've set both ServerName and ServerAlias for all hosts, the server is not sending back a server name.

Here's my Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.io
    ServerAlias example.io
    Redirect permanent / https://example.io
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName api.example.io
    ServerAlias api.example.io
    Redirect permanent / https://api.example.io
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName store.example.io
    ServerAlias store.example.io
    Redirect permanent / https://store.example.io
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.io
    ServerAlias example.io
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/file.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/file.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/file.crt

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "I have a problem with an Apache machine that won't return a server name, which results in some clients implementing SNI returning an error." - this does not make sense for me. The clients sends the server name it expects in the ClientHello. There is no server name returned by the server.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood this. The client sends the server name it expects, but it ain't matching and Apache sends back a warning. I'll just update my question.

Comment: You have only a single certificate configured. This certificate gets delivered. If the contents of the certificate does not match the expected name the client will complain. For SNI you need multiple certificates. Or you have a certificate with multiple names in which case you don't even need SNI.

Comment: My certificate is a wildcard certificate. You say that i won't need SNI, will this mean that it would be something that I can disable? Browsers are responding fine to my configuration but Java clients interprets this warning as an error and refuses connection.

Comment: You don't need to disable or enable SNI. There is probably something else wrong with your setup. Could you please tell the URL of your site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a problem of SNI but of a missing chain certificate. From the report of [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=genderize.io&latest):

```
Chain issues    Incomplete
...
2   Extra download  RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3 
Fingerprint: 0e34141846e7423d37f20dc0ab06c9bbd843dc24
```

Desktop browsers have these missing chain certificates often cached from other sites or download them. Other applications or mobile browsers mostly just fail in this case.

Apart from that you have other setup problems, like offering weak ciphers (RC4) and protocol (SSL3.0).

> TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Warning, Description: Unrecognized Name)

This is probably because you have a ServerName example.io but the client uses www.example.io which does not match the ServerName you gave. You will not get an error at the client side because the certificate matches the name the client uses. You should probably use

```
 ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
```

to make this warning go away.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The ServerAlias did the job in terms of the warning. If was able to fix the Chain issues as well. I had no idea that multiple intermediate certificates could be concatinated into one bundle, that caused my problems.